# How can I include an image on a PDF generated using XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, image, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

i'm doing an XLST transformation from XML to PDF using Apache FOP.
Now I need to include an external image from local in that PDF and I have no idea about how to do this.
Anyone knows how can I do this? Maybe adding some kind of instruction on the XSL stylesheet?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT creates an XSL-FO document and that can include an http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_external-graphic `fo:external-graphic` element. So you will need to adapt the XSLT to create such a `fo:external-graphic` element.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I just reached the same solution :)